# How do I increase the frame length of a websocket?

Tags: swift, websocket, vapor

When I send large amount of JSON over a WebSocket connection to a vapor swift server, the connection closes with the following error:

> invalidFrameLength

The error description is:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NIOWebSocket.NIOWebSocketError error 0.)

My configure.swift looks like this:

```
let webSocketServer: NIOWebSocketServer = NIOWebSocketServer.default()
try sockets(webSocketServer)
services.register(webSocketServer, as: WebSocketServer.self)
```

And the socket function:

```
public func sockets(_ webSocketServer: NIOWebSocketServer) throws {
    webSocketServer.get("example") { (webSocket: WebSocket, request: Request) in

    }
}
```

How would I increase the frame length on the server side to be able to sent large JSON?

Comment: I do believe that the size can be increased only on the server side. So you should ask the person managing it to increase the maximum frame size allowed.

Comment: I have access to the server and the client. How do I increase it on the server?

Comment: Check the `maxFrameSize` parameter [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/blob/2.13.0/Sources/NIOWebSocket/WebSocketFrameDecoder.swift#L21), you should have something similar there as well.

Comment: I added my server side code, where do I add the maxFrameLength?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible using Vapor 4:

```swift
app.webSocket("route", maxFrameSize: .init(integerLiteral: 1 << 24)) { (request: Request, webSocket: WebSocket) in
    // code ...
}
```

```swift
app.webSocket("route", maxFrameSize: 16_777_216) { (request: Request, webSocket: WebSocket) in
    // code ...
}
```